# Dataframe Duplicate a row under a certain condition inside a cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe, column "Reference" can have more than one word (separated by space blank " ")

```
Col1    Col2      Col3    Reference

Apple   Broccoli  Frog    M1139 M1944 
Orange  Tomato    Rope    M1134
Potato  Tuna      Lemon   M1129 M1944 M2944
```

I would like to create a duplicate of the entire row if there is more than one word in column "Reference", writing each word in each line.

For example in row 1 there are 2 words in "Reference" M1139 M1944,therefore two lines are created:

Desired output:

```
Col1    Col2      Col3    Reference

Apple   Broccoli  Frog    M1139
Apple   Broccoli  Frog    M1944
Orange  Tomato    Rope    M1134
Potato  Tuna      Lemon   M1129
Potato  Tuna      Lemon   M1944
Potato  Tuna      Lemon   M2944
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df2 = (df
       .assign(Reference=df['Reference'].str.split(' '))
       .explode('Reference')
       )
```

Output:

```
     Col1      Col2   Col3 Reference
0   Apple  Broccoli   Frog     M1139
0   Apple  Broccoli   Frog     M1944
1  Orange    Tomato   Rope     M1134
2  Potato      Tuna  Lemon     M1129
2  Potato      Tuna  Lemon     M1944
2  Potato      Tuna  Lemon     M2944
```

By default, `explode` duplicates the values of the row indices as well. If you want to reset the index, you can pass `ignore_index=True` to `explode`:

```
df3 = (df
       .assign(Reference=df['Reference'].str.split(' '))
       .explode('Reference', ignore_index=True)
       )
```

Output:

```
     Col1      Col2   Col3 Reference
0   Apple  Broccoli   Frog     M1139
1   Apple  Broccoli   Frog     M1944
2  Orange    Tomato   Rope     M1134
3  Potato      Tuna  Lemon     M1129
4  Potato      Tuna  Lemon     M1944
5  Potato      Tuna  Lemon     M2944
```